# Why won't my code store ints into my temps array?

Tags: arraylist

```
System.out.print("What would you like to decode? ");
        String fileName1 = console.next();
        System.out.print("Save the results as: ");
        resultFileName = console.next();
        int token1;
        Scanner inFile1 = new Scanner(new 
File(fileName1)).useDelimiter("[" + "," + " ]");
        List<Integer> temps = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while (inFile1.hasNext()) {
            token1 = inFile1.nextInt();
            temps.add(token1);
            }
        for(int i = 0; i <= temps.size() - 1; i++) {
            int x = temps.get(i);
            System.out.print((char) x); 
        }
```

when i run this it says there is a error on "token1 = inFile1.nextInt();"

this is what is in the file: [89, 111, 117, 39, 114, 101, 32, 97, 108, 109, 111, 115, 116, 32, 116, 104, 101, 114, 101, 46, 32, 75, 101, 101, 112, 32, 117, 112, 32, 116, 104, 101, 32, 103, 111, 111, 100, 32, 119, 111, 114, 107, 33]

Answer (score 0):

Use the `inFile1.hasNextInt()` opposed to the `inFile1.hasNext()`. This way you can make sure the next value can be interpreted as an `int`.

I think the `inFile1.hasNext()` is resolving as `true` because you still have the character `]` left in the file.

Answer (score 0):

The `useDelimiter` is only used to seperate your `ints`. So you have to manually parse the `[` and `]` and call `Scanner inFile1 = new Scanner(new 
File(fileName1)).useDelimiter(",");` for parsing the `ints`.

Edit: for parsing the '[' for example you can use:
`Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[");
scanner.next(p);`

Comment: how would i parse the [ and ]?